# How can I set up aliases using bash in Solaris 5.10

Tags: bash, solaris, alias

Environment:  SunRay terminal, running on Solaris 5.10 host.  SHELL=/bin/bash

Goal: set up some aliases for long commands

Trying a simple alias:
alias p='pwd'

I've tried to add this alias to .bash_profile, .aliases and .aliases with no luck.  In linux I'd put the aliase in .bash_profile.   Where should I put it in Solaris?

Comment: Do you have a `~/.profile`?  Also did you restart your session after adding to `.bash_profile`?

Comment: To see which files are relevant, read [Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files) in the bash manual

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They should go in your `~/.bashrc` file.   Solaris will also use `.bash_profile` though so it's odd that isn't working for you.

Note: You will have to restart your session (Or at least source the `.bashrc` file) before the aliases placed in there will be available.

Comment: That did it.  .bashrc file was not in the $HOME directory.   I created the file and set up an alias.  Success!